# Error : dimensions don't match the number of cells

Tags: r, dataframe, logistic-regression, data-modeling, mixed-models

I would like to run a mixed-effect conditional logistic regression on some animal movement data but no matter what I try I keep getting the error:

```
Error in `dim<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(d, m.k)) : 
  dimensions don't match the number of cells
```

Can someone help me understand how the dimensions of my data do not match the number of cells? Any insight as to what this might mean and how to remedy it would be appreciated as I am fairly new to R and haven't been able to find any clues online. I have played with different variables and whether or not Animal.ID and Step.ID should be factors or numeric.

My code is as follows:

```
library(mclogit)

# Create data frame
locations <- data.table(Animal.ID = as.factor(c(4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4002, 4002, 4002, 4003, 4003, 4003)),
                        Used = as.factor(c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0)),
                        Step.ID = c(2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                        Roads_3 = c(0.21, 0.55, -0.13, 0.1, -0.63, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3,-0.44,0.92,-0.01, 0.15),
                        Elevation = c(0.2391, 0.1937, 0.0533, 0.1978, -0.1656, 0.284, 0.247, -0.0623, 0.313, 0.432, -0.123, 0.111))

# Check dimensions and make sure all variables look alright
str(locations)

# My attempts at modeling
m1 <- mclogit(cbind(Used, Step.ID) ~ Elevation + Roads_3, random = ~Roads_3|Animal.ID, data = locations)
m2 <- mclogit(cbind(Used, Step.ID) ~ Elevation + Roads_3, random = ~Elevation|Animal.ID, data = locations)
m3 <- mclogit(cbind(Used, Step.ID) ~ Elevation, random = ~Roads_3|Animal.ID, data = locations)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know much about mixed-effect conditional logistic regression. Shouldn't the components in random argument be numeric? m1 <- mclogit(cbind(Used, Step.ID) ~ Elevation + Animal.ID, random = ~ 1|Roads_3, data = locations)

Comment: According to the `mclogit` documentation, the first column of the matrix on the left of the formula should be `0` or `1`, whereas you have them as factors. Try taking the `as.factor` off the definition of `Used`. The source of the error might be in your `random = ...` term, I think. If you remove the `random` argument, it seems to work.

Comment: Thank you for your responses Mohanasundaram and Andrew Gustar. I tried running the models with the response/'Used' being numeric, as well as having Animal.ID be numeric with no avail. I have also played with Step.ID being numeric vs a factor but believe it should probably be numeric since the values repeat for each animal. I do believe the issue could be with the random term as models without it do run, however the main reason I would like to use mclogit is to account for variation between my individuals since they live in a variety of ecoregions.

Comment: I have to incorporate Animal.ID as random slopes and random intercepts since in conditional logistic regression any variables that are constant within strata are cancelled out, hence the ```random = ~Roads_3|Animal.ID``` rather than ```random = ~1|Animal.ID```